# ListView.builder inside PageView inside SingleChildScrollView gets Unbounded Height Error

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter Doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Minimal Reproducible Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Temp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Temp> createState() => _TempState();
}

class _TempState extends State<Temp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
        margin:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top + 10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('DUMMY BOX 3'))),
              Container(
                  color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('DUMMY BOX 2'))),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('DUMMY BOX 3'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              PageView(
                controller: pageController,
                children: const [
                  DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
                  DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
                  DummyListViewContainerWidget()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DummyListViewContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DummyListViewContainerWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 10,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        separatorBuilder: (cxt, index) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          );
        },
        itemBuilder: (cxt, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.brown,
            child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**Expectations** :
Whole screen is scrollable not just ListView.

**Tried Solutions**:

1. Giving column below of SingleChildScrollView to MainAxisSize.min
2. Giving Height To PageView which is not a solution to my case. giving height to it will only show view of DummyListViewContainerWidget to that height and will cut the rest of it.
3. Removing SingleChildScrollView From Top and putting in inside PageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `CustomScrollView`, something like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
      ]),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: true,
      child: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        children: [
          DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
          DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
          DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I have implemented the SliverFillRemaining and this CustomScrollView as your solution. But the problem in this is that screen only shows DummyListViewContainerWidget() up to the same height as the combination of the first three Container Widgets. After that, it doesn't scroll more.

Comment: If you want the whole screen to be scrollable instead of just `ListView`, then put `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code to make the whole thing work :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Temp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Temp> createState() => _TempState();
}

class _TempState extends State<Temp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
        margin:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top + 10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('DUMMY BOX 3'))),
              Container(
                  color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('DUMMY BOX 2'))),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('DUMMY BOX 3'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //you just needed to add a definite height to your PageView
                child: PageView(
                  controller: pageController,
                  children: const [
                    DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
                    DummyListViewContainerWidget(),
                    DummyListViewContainerWidget()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DummyListViewContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DummyListViewContainerWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 10,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        separatorBuilder: (cxt, index) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          );
        },
        itemBuilder: (cxt, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.brown,
            child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

It was pretty much just that `PageView` which was causing that error handling it made the code work flawlessly.

Comment: I already told in " tried solutions " that giving height is not a solution, giving the height will not show all DummyListViewContainerWidget data after scrolling.

Comment: why though, have you tried giving dynamic height to the widget?

Comment: dynamic height?

Comment: yeah check the code that I've written for you

Comment: can you point to this dynamic height? If you're talking about the line where you commented " you just needed to add a definite height... ", then it is just the height of the screen. It does not let me scroll after the height.